# What is the difference between merge and flatmap operator in RxSwift

Tags: merge, rx-swift, reactive, flatmap

I am currently new to RxSwift and I am a little bit confused about the flatMap and merge operator. I know the merge operator merges more than one observable into a single observable. I feel that flatMap is doing the same thing.Am I wrong? If so what is the difference between both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `merge` operator and `flatMap` both merge the output of several observables into one observable. The difference is in where the observables being merged come from.

For the `merge` operator, there must be a static number of observables already in existence (for the static merge method) or a sequence of observables that are emitted together (for the non-static merge method).

For the `flatMap` operator, the observables that are being merged are generated dynamically by the closure passed to the operator.